# Evangelion: Where are the Angels coming from?

Tags: evangelion

Is there any place I can read / watch that I can find-out something more about the Angels. I just finished watching Rebuild from 1.0 to 3.0, and it looks like everyone calls these strange beings "Angels", but why is that? Where are they coming from?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Why are the angels called that way ?**

The answer can be found here:

[Symbolism of the cross in Evangelion](http://web.archive.org/web/20031208113458/www.akadot.com/article/article-tsurumaki2.html)

> Because Christianity is an uncommon religion in Japan we thought it would be mysterious. 
>   [...]
>   We just thought the visual symbols of Christianity look cool. If we had known the show would get distributed in the US and Europe we might have rethought that choice.

Comment: That's not a bad answer from the OOC perspective.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my accepted answer, since this one provides an actual reason. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

***Note: This answer is based on the original series, it's accompanying movie and printed materials, and Rebuild 1.0 & 2.0.***

No one truly knows, or if they do it was never disclosed in any of the official materials. All we know is that they are beings with tremendous power that have DNA that is %99.89 similar to human DNA. It is also stated that humans are descended from the Angel known as Lilith (the white giant imprisoned inside Terminal Dogma) while the sixteen Angels that threaten humanity are descended from the Angel known as Adam (whose only remaining part is inside the brief case Kaji delivers to NERV). Also not known is the source of their naming. Were they the *source* of the stories of their biblical counterparts, or were they named *after* the fact using the Bible as a guide? Though personally I tend to lean towards the latter.

Comment: The [Lilith](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lilith) related to Adam is from Jewish folklore not directly from the Bible. Also could you address the OP's other question about why they are called "Angels"? +1 anyway for a useful answer.

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton - I believe the naming part is covered by the last part of my answer. They are either the angels that the biblical names refer to, or they are called angels following the biblical naming convention set up by NERV.

Comment: But the Biblical Adam was not an angel. One thread of the folklore of Lilith has her mating with an angel, so their children might be considered demi-angels. Less precise use of terms is not uncommon and not necessarily bad but could use explanation. (By the way, angel comes from the [old] Greek for messenger [a common role for these beings in the Bible] and evangelion is a quasi-transliteration [really, euangelion] of the Greek for "good news" [good message] also called gospel.)